# children centered in a row

Tags: widget, flutter, row

Im using Align Widget to center children in a Row but It is not working...what I doing wrong?

This is the code:

....
home.dart
....

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context){
_context = context;

return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(title: Text("MiniCon")),

    body: new Container(child: new Column(children:[
    new Align(alignment:Alignment.center,child:new Row(children:[
    _commons.makeEditText("Ahorro Real", grey, false),
    _commons.makeEditText("Ahorro Actual", black, true),
    _commons.makeEditText("Gastos", black, true)
  ])),


  new Row(children:[
    _commons.makeEditText("Ahorro Real", grey, false)
  ])
  ])));
}
```

....
_commons.dart
....

```
Widget makeEditText(String label, Color labelColor, bool enabled) {
return 
new Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(2.5), child:
new Container(decoration: 
new BoxDecoration(border: 
new Border.all(width:2.0)),padding: new 
new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),width:110.0,child:
new TextField(enabled: enabled,
  style: TextStyle(color: labelColor),
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0), labelText: label),
)));
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Centers the Row:

```
body: Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            makeEditText("Ahorro Real", Colors.grey, false),
            makeEditText("Ahorro Actual", Colors.black, true),
            makeEditText("Gastos", Colors.green, true)
          ]),
          new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [makeEditText("Ahorro Real", Colors.red, false)])
        ]),
      ),
```

Comment: Happy To help ! @PabloLanzaMoreno

Answer (score 0):

Use the mainAxisAlignment / crossAxisAlignment property of the Column/Row widgets instead.